# What is so special about the principal value branch of inverse trigonometric functions.

Tags: trigonometry

Why only a specific branch of a inverse trigonometric functions is called principal value branch? For example in questions like  this- what will be the value of the function sin^-1(sinx), if x lies in certain branch? -we try to modify the concerned branch into principal branch and find the value of sin^-1(sinx). Why principal branch is so unique?

Comment: Essentially customary.  $0\le x \le 2\pi$ is a full circle.  Adding $2n\pi$. doesn't add any information.

Comment: It's a convention. Same reason why we *define* $\sqrt x$ to be the nonnegative (whereas non positive too would have done) real number $y$ satisfying $y^2=x.$ However, the agreed upon convention in this case is the more convenient based on the convention (again!) of indicating negative real numbers by the pre-symbol $-.$